# Iterative Depth First Search To Find A String (2D Array)

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, depth-first-search

I'm trying to create an iterative approach to a boggle game. The class contains fields for a 2d Array of Strings called "board" and has a 2d array of booleans called "haveVisit". The method that calls test 2 loops through the whole board, finding positions of the first character of the target string, then passes the coordinates into the test2 method, returning a list holding coordinates.

The return1Index method takes a 2D array coordinate at creates a int representative of the coordinates from a corresponding 1d array from it. The return2DIndex does the opposite and returns an int array holding the two coordinates.

```
public List<Integer> test2(int row1, int row2, String findMe){
     String temp = findMe;
     List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     if (board[row1][row2].charAt(0) != findMe.charAt(0))
        return output;
     haveVisit = new boolean[size][size];
     int row = row1; 
     int column = row2;                                    
     output.add(return1DIndex(row, column));           
     haveVisit[row][column] = true;                   

     //for each letter in the string
     for(int j = 0; j < temp.length(); j++)

        //for every column and row combination
        for (int x = row - 1; x < row + 2 ; x++)
           for (int y = column - 1; y < column + 2 ; y++)

              //if index is valid and not visited
              if (x > -1 && y > -1 && y < size && x < size && !haveVisit[x][y])
                 //if the output is the same size as string, return
                 if(output.size() == findMe.length())
                    return output;

                 //if the character in the board matches the char we're looking for
                 if(board[x][y].charAt(0) == temp.charAt(j))
                 {
                    haveVisit[x][y] = true;
                    output.add(return1DIndex(x, y));

                    //update row and column indices
                    row = x;
                    column = y;
                 }
              }
           }
     return output;
  }
```

For some reason this method works only 50% of the time. The method works fine with finding the letters when they're arranged left to right or top to bottom, but finding words from right to left or bottom to top never works except for one case: when you're searching for a string of length 1 or 2, where this method always works.

I have a working recursive solution but I wanted to try this way. Any thoughts as to why this wouldn't work?

Edit: Code now works from right to left, but still does not work when attempting to search upwards.

Comment: Depth first search usually uses three colors (white, grey, black), not two... see this: http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/GraphAlgor/depthSearch.htm

Comment: Neat! I'll give it a shot. When I view the array of booleans, the only indices that are true are those that contain the strings that form the target word. 

I don't know why that would cause every directional search to work besides upwards, though.

Comment: You may also want to try creating a data structure `class Cell { String value; Color color; }` and having one two dimensional array instead of two. It should make your code much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but there are a few suspects:

- You are updating row and column indices while checking their neighbors. This is like removing an element from an array while iterating through it: it's well defined, but has tricky semantics. I suggest either bailing out (greedy algorithm) or keeping a stack of matches (deeper search, requires saving stack of visited cells too).
- The `for`s are missing opening braces, but the closing braces are there, suggesting missing code.
- I'm not familiar with boggle, but isn't it possible for a letter to have two similar neighbors, like `AXA`? By just doing `output.add(return1DIndex(x, y));` you may be outputting two ways to get the same letter. You may end up with `output` longer than `findMe`.

My suggestion is to follow a more standard format of depth-first search while you iron out the bugs. Wikipedia has a non-recursive pseudocode implementation, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode .